# How do I cause the controller buttons to display for an Apple Quicktime video embedded in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, browser, plugins, quicktime

I am trying to embed a Quicktime video in Firefox, but when I do the controller buttons do not appear.  I've tried both the old style embed tag and the new style object tags, but when I set the "controller" option to true there is no change in the appearance of the plugin.  The video loads, but it is zoomed in on some portion of the video and there are no buttons to play, pause, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a article possibly related to this.

There seems to be a general problem with quicktime for people using Vista 64bit, so if you are it might be your not the code but your computer.

http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=mk&comments_parentId=308231&forumId=1

Answer (score 0):

It could very possibly be that your embed script's `width` and `height` attributes are smaller than the movie. If they are the exact dimensions of the movie, then you should try increasing the `height` attribute value, as the controls might be at the bottom. This solved the same/similar issue recently for me.

Answer (score 0):

The height has to set to larger after searching entire web...I figured this out...:-)